# What is the chance that the balls are evenly distributed in the box?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six different balls are kept into 3 different boxes randomly so that no box being empty.What is the chance that the balls are evenly distributed in the box?
I have learnt one formula that number of ways in which $m\times n$ different objects can be distributed equally among $n$ persons$=\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^n}$
So the number of ways in which 6 different objects can be distributed equally among 3 boxes$=\frac{6!}{(2!)^3}$
I counted the total number of ways as$\binom{6-1}{3-1}=10$
But this is giving me the wrong answer,correct answer is $\frac{1}{6}$.What mistake have i done?
Is evenly distributed not same as the equally distributed?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{6!}{2^3}$ is correct for favorable ways,

But total ways of putting *distinct* balls into *distinct* boxes would be $3^6$, as each ball has $3$ choices for box.

[edit:]

However, as we *also* need to restrict this so that no box is empty, we use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (PIE) to exclude when *at least 1* box is empty.   So that is $3^6-3\cdot 2^6 +3$

$$\dfrac{6!}{2^3(3^6-3\cdot 2^6+3)} = \dfrac 1 6$$

Comment: But that will not give me probability $\frac{1}{6}$@trueblueanil

Comment: It's $3^6 - 3\cdot 2^6 + 3$ ways to put distinct balls into distinct boxes so that no box is empty. @user1442

Comment: @Graham: Thanks, I missed one condition by oversight .

Answer (score 1):

The balls are numbered from one to six, and each of them went into one of the boxes $A$, $B$, $C$ with equal probability, and independently. A priori there would be $3^6$ equiprobable cases, but we are told that none of the boxes remained empty. In any case the result of the experiment can be encoded as a word of length $6$ over the alphabet $\{A,B,C\}$.

Cardinalitywise there  are  three different types of admissible distributions of the six balls, namely $$T_1:\ 4+1+1, \qquad T_2: \ 3+2+1, \qquad T_3: \  2+2+2\ .$$
We now have to count the number of words for each of the three types. For type $T_1$ we can choose the letter occurring four times in $3$ ways; then we can place the four equal letters in ${6\choose 4}$ ways, and finally we can allocate the two remaining letters in $2$ ways, making a total of $90$ words of type $T_1$. For $T_2$ we can choose the letter occurring three times in $3$ ways and the letter occurring two times in $2$ ways. Then we can place these letters in ${6!\over 3!\>2!\>1!}$ ways, making a total of $360$ words of type $T_2$. For $T_3$ we can place $A$ in ${6\choose2}$ ways, then $B$ in ${4\choose 2}$ ways, and the two last slots  are for $C$. This amounts to $90$ words of type $T_3$.

The probability in question is then given by
$${|T_3|\over|T_1|+|T_2|+|T_3|}={90\over90+360+90}={1\over6}\ .$$