# What does evenly distributed mean?

Tags: terminology

I, repeatedly, find this expression used in many places, especially when talking about probabilities. I am interested in understanding the meaning of the expression in a $2$-dimensional and $3$-dimensional spaces.

Let's say we have a set $S$ of $N$ objects that have the same shape.

1. What does it mean to evenly distribute the set of objects $S$ on an  rectangular area $A$ ?
2. The same question but $A$ is now $3$-dimensional space.

Comment: "uniformly distributed". *Uniformly* must be understood with respect to a defined criteria. Your example seems quite strange... do you have a reference for it ?

Comment: There is some question below but it does not have to do with geometry. In geometrical sense, I guess it would mean the center of the objects are placed with the same distance from one another. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462382/what-is-the-chance-that-the-balls-are-evenly-distributed-in-the-box